# How Best to Extend C# App via Abstract Classes

Tags: c#

I've got about six months experience in C#, and have come up against my first puzzle which I can't solve myself, using regular training material on the Internet.

I want to apply many different filters to a video, by extending some software (.NET Framework 4.0).

I **must** implement the abstract class, Video, which has two methods, Create() and Calc().

Create is used to instantiate any new objects I may need, and Calc runs once per frame of the video, starting from the first to last frame.

```
public class MyRedEyeFilter: Video
{
    public MyRedEyeFilter(object c) : base(c) {}

    protected override Create() {
        // documentation says this is the place to new up anything we want.
    }

    protected override Calc() {
        // documentation says this is where we perform an action
        // on each frame of the video, staring from first to last.
        RemoveRedEye();
    }

    public void RemoveRedEye() {
        Console.WriteLine("Red eyes removed for this frame.");
    }

}
```

My requirement is such that I want to run all my filters on the video. I havn't yet thought of a situation where I don't need all of them for each video. E.g. I have a RemoveRedEye filter above, but I also have 50 or so more filters, which at the moment I run by creating a massive list of "new" commands in the Create() method of a filter named "AllMyFilters".

Simply put, I will need to not only maintain my code, but I've got many new filters that still need implementing. Am I doing this right? If not, what should I start reading up on, or what is the best way to go about this in your opinion?

If nothing else, I would be most grateful, for some pointers, so that at least I can try to learn something.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: 50 or more filters? every frame? howcomputationally heavy are those filters? Depending on the video you might only have like 1s/60 or fewer ms time to do all those things you want to do. Highspeed cameras give you even less time...

Comment: Generally you do not "extend" a c# App class via abstract classes. The abstract class is the base class and you implement the abstract methods your derived class gets fro - but thats just semantics

Comment: @PatrickArtner I should have mentioned, these videos are no more than say a hundred frames. They are actually passed to me by someone else, who basically says to me "these frames from our video need tweaking, please can you sort it, thanks". Also, the filters are not very heavy. They just each do very small things.

Comment: It seems these are hypothetical filters. I am pretty sure by `Create` they meant the constructor and not a method named `Create`. Design it from the perspective of the user: What if they altogether forget to call `Create` and call `RemoveRedEye` before calling `Create`? Also if `Calc` calls `RemoveRedEye`, `Calc` may never be called. What is the point of `object` parameter in the constructor? You have not given enough information to give you appropriate feedback.

Comment: You speak of abstract classes but no such class is shown in your design. Also, since the only public is `RemoveRedEye`, I don't see the point of the protected method and what role they would play.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Most likely code in the base class will call the overriden methods, but it would be helpful to see the `Video` class to better understand how this is all suppose to work.

Comment: @juharr Not possible with current design to treat the objects polymorphically. Even if base classes called them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer this objectively, but it sounds like you're writing e.g. a plugin for some video production software like Vegas Studio; you write code as per spec, you compile it to a DLL, you drop it in the folder of the software, the software finds it, finds all your classes that descend from `Video`, and loads them into an internal list of filters in the software.

The user will then select which filters to apply, which may include some of your filters. At the start of the video your code's Create() will be called (if your filter is one of those in the chain), and then `Calc()` is called repeatedly as the software processes the video frames, though how your code gets access to the frame data, I'm not sure.. Perhaps it was the object passed to the constructor? If `Calc` is just called once per video I'm not really sure why you need a `Create` that is called once per video

As such, I don't think it's intended that you load 50 filters worth of code (that you haven't written yet) into one filter. I think you should write 50 filters as separate things, because the user of the software will decide which of your 50 filters they want to activate.

If you want to write one super duper filter that performs 50 operations per frame then crack on, but it's not very flexible based on what i'd imagine it is supposed to work like (based on what I've seen of other video editing softwares where filters are chained and have just one job, filter order is managed by the software, not you). If, of course, you're a video editor who is quite code-capable, and one of your jobs is to perform the same 50 operations on every video the client sends you, then sure - load it all into one filter plugin; this way you can just activate the ShaarpeSuperSaver plugin per video and save a bunch of time in setting up the software filter list ...

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because even though I said I needed to use every filter, you are making me doubt that point. After sleeping on it, I may in fact get superior quality results by not using some combinations of filters with some other ones, even though I  get acceptable results with them all turned on. I will now focus on how I can combine them well, so I am applying less filters to get better results. It's just an idea, but I will go down that path in the hope of a better end result.